# SVN Where is SVN version control files stored locally?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

Yes that's what I'm concerned about because I can't find it anywhere in my local computer. And do I need to know much about that?

Answer (score 2):

The SVN working copy information is stored in hidden directories named `.svn`. Read more about the contents of these folders in [*Learning Subversion: the mystery of .svn*](https://pythonconquerstheuniverse.wordpress.com/2011/03/16/learning-subversion-the-mystery-of-svn-2/).